# How to find the index of 5 numbers nearest to a chosen number in a dataframe column pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say that my column x has nine numbers from 1-9. If I chose 4, I would get the index of 1,2,3,4,5 in x because 4 is the closest number to 4 and then 1,2,3,5 are the next closest numbers to 4. I looked at a similar post to this but it did not account for a number being closest to itself. This is what I have currently but I am wondering if I can add something to it to account for that last test case I mentioned.

```
df_sort = df.iloc[(df['x']-xseq).abs().argsort()[:6]]
index = df_sort.index.tolist()
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data to explain the edge case you're concerned with?

Comment: @piRSquared basically if I have a column which contains numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. If  choose a number, I would like to get the indexes of the 5 nearest numbers. If I choose 4, since 4 is in that column, 4 would be included in the indexes returned. I would get the indexes of 1,2,3,4,5 since those are the nearest numbers to 4. If I chose 10, I would get the indexes of 5,6,7,8,9 since those are the 5 nearest numbers from 10. I hope this clarifies my question.

Comment: I undeleted my answer, but it is nearly identical to what you tried.  So I'm confused as to what the issue is.  Also, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 are the not the closest to 4... its 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.

Comment: @piRSquared oh yea you are correct sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 1):

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(1, 10)})
```

---

#### Pandas `nsmallest`

```
df.loc[df.x.sub(4).abs().nsmallest(5).index]

   x
3  4
2  3
4  5
1  2
5  6
```

---

#### Numpy's `argpartition`

```
df.iloc[np.argpartition(np.abs(df.x.to_numpy() - 4), 5)[:5]]

   x
5  6
4  5
2  3
3  4
1  2
```